# Why symfony 2 uses both, the 'deps' file and the 'composer.json' file?

Tags: symfony

Why symfony 2 uses both, the `deps` file and the `composer.json` file?

I can see some documents tell me to:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

Whilst the other tell me to:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `deps` file and `bin/vendors` script are used in Symfony 2.0.x, while Symfony 2.1.x has switched to Composer. The `bin/vendors` script was just a stub because Composer was not ready for production when Symfony 2.0.0 was released.

Comment: `bin/vendors` seems to have functionality that Composer does not (and shouldn't be expected to) have, such as copying assets from vendor bundles to `web/bundles`.

Comment: There is the `assets:install` command for that and `bin/vendors` just calls it at the end of its run.

Comment: The point is that `php composer.phar install` does not call it. So unless you really know what you are doing, you are better off using `bin/vendors`, which will call Composer anyway, but might do other useful stuff as well.

Comment: I didn't like the `vendors` script to install assets anyway — I had to resymlink them again each time after installing/updating vendors, so I'm happy that Composer doesn't do it too. ;)

Comment: @Tgr `bin/vendors` will **not** call Composer anyway, they're two separate things. You can call `assets:install` with Composer via script hooks: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: Just adding some info which I believe has been wrongly posted in the comments:

Composer HAS the functionality to copy assets to web/bundles, and even creating symlinks in assets.
Refer to this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup (just scroll up a bit, to the subsection "Updating Vendors")


To create symlinks instead of copying the assets, you can add an entry in the extra node of your composer.json file with the key symfony-assets-install and the value symlink: