# What is the deps file?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install a plugin for Symfony 2 , looking up how to do this I keep seeing reference to something called the "deps file" but I'm not sure which file this is referring too.

I can't find any file in my symfony folder called "deps"

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283680/why-symfony-2-uses-both-the-deps-file-and-the-composer-json-file

Comment: maybe your plugin is available via composer. should be easier to install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably use Symfony2.1 which  does not use deps file, instead, uses composer. In Symfony2.0 deps file is located at the top level of the application.

Deps (for Symfony2.0) and composer.json (for Symfony2.1+) files are used for installing third parties (vendors) and also core files of Symfony